# Scroll position is not saved

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to realize a simple task: I need a random number to be generated when a button is pressed, and when the screen is rotated, the numbers and the scroll position are preserved. But for some reason I am not able to implement this funcionality, the scroll position is not saved. What could be the reason?

```
    class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
            if (savedInstanceState != null){
                val scrollPosition = savedInstanceState.getInt("scrollPosition")
                val scrollView = findViewById<ScrollView>(R.id.scrollView)
                scrollView.post { scrollView.scrollTo(0, scrollPosition) }
                val count = savedInstanceState.getInt("viewsCount")
                for (i in 0 until count)
                    addTextView()
            }
    
        }
    
        fun buttonAddClick(view: View) {
    
            addTextView()
    
    
        }
    
        private var viewsCount = 0
    
        fun addTextView() {
    
            viewsCount = rand(1..100)
            val textView = TextView(this)
            textView.text = viewsCount.toString()
            textView.textSize = 20f
            val container = findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.innerConteiner)
            container.addView(textView)
    
        }
    
    
    
        override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle) {
            super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
            outState.putInt("viewsCount", viewsCount)
            outState.putInt("scrollposition", findViewById<ScrollView>(R.id.scrollView).scrollY)
        }
    
    
        fun rand(range: IntRange): Int {
            require(range.first <= range.last) { "Illegal Argument" }
            return Random(System.nanoTime()).nextInt(range) + range.first
        }
    
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried logging in to the activity lifecycle? When a screen rotates, the oncreate method is triggered again which makes your data to be reinitialized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't go through the code, but I think this is a **typo**

while retrieving you are using **"scrollPosition"**

```
val scrollPosition = savedInstanceState.getInt("scrollPosition")
```

but while saving you are using **"scrollposition"**

```
outState.putInt("scrollposition", findViewById<ScrollView>(R.id.scrollView).scrollY)
```